# Is it wrong to call main from another function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I've been wondering if it is bad practice to call main from another function to essentially re-run the program if certain conditions do not apply.

Here's a code example.

```
def main():
        userInput = input("Please input a word(\"terminate\" exits): ")
        if(len(userInput)>=5):
            wordLength(userInput)     
        else:
            wordLength()
        

def wordLength(word = "Default print"):
    
    if (word != "Terminate"):
        print(word)
        main()
    
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Is this bad practice and should I do it in a different way than this? Perhaps with a while loop?

Comment: In Python, there is nothing special about `main` or whatever you call your entry point function.  However, from a design perspective it could certainly be confusing to future readers.

Comment: This depends entirely on your application. If it recurses a few times, it might well be worth it. If the recursion condition is difficult to aggregate into one loop, it might well be worth it. If it hits the recursion limit, it might still be worth it after increasing the recursion limit.

Comment: There's no reason at all to use recursion for the purpose of validating user's input. Use a while loop instead to keep asking for user's input until the validation condition is met.

Comment: That would be the better and more readable solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a while loop here. It is not "bad" to call main from another function, but this pattern is not widely used and would be difficult for future maintainers (even hypothetical ones) to read and understand.

It is also generally not recommended to have this type of cyclical recursive function call if at all avoidable for the same reason as well as adding even more memory to the stack.

Keep in mind that there is an edge case and exception to almost all established design rules and patterns (those listed here included), so it is a good idea to ask for second opinions when you think you might to "reinvent the wheel."